# C++ Конвертировать цвет c hex (std::wstring) к COLORREF

Tags: c++, winapi

Как конвертировать в C++ цвет c hex (std::wstring) к COLORREF?

```
static COLORREF GetRGB(std::wstring hex) { // "#ffffff"
  return RGB(255, 255, 255);
}
```

И как можно сделать валидацию строки?

и еще что собственно такое COLORREF? unsigned int?

Comment: Можете привести пример такого преобразования? Что-то вроде `"ff7f00"` -> `uint8_t r = 0xff, g = 0x7f, b = 0;`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat привел

Comment: На вскидку: Проверить, что первый символ - `#`, а за ним - 6 шестнадцатеричных цифр. Преобразовать каждую цифру в число от 0 до 15. Для каждого цвета домножить значение первой цифры на 16 и прибавить значение второй цифры.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а COLORREF равен unsigned int? На MSDN прочитал что COLORREF ето DWORD

Comment: Не представляю. Но это и не должно быть важно, если пользоваться `RGB(...)`.